# CakePHP model useTable with SQL Views

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, cakephp

I'm in the process converting our CakePHP-built website from Pervasive to SQL Server 2005.  After a lot of hassle the setup I've gotten to work is using the ADODB driver with 'connect' as odbc_mssql. This connects to our database and builds the SQL queries just fine.

However, here's the rub: one of our Models was associated with an SQL view in Pervasive.  I ported over the view, but it appears using the set up that I have that CakePHP can't find the View in SQL Server.

Couldn't find much after some Google searches - has anyone else run into a problem like this?  Is there a solution/workaround, or is there some redesign in my future?

Comment: I've built CakePHP models against views in MySQL before and it worked as expected (though, you obviously can't write to a view, only read data from it). Perhaps SQL Server presents views in a manner different from other RDBMS?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, which version of CakePHP are you using? I'll assume it's about CakePHP 1.2+.

### The problem

I'm not familiar with SQL Server 2005 (nor any other versions), but after some investigation, I think the problem is in `DboMssql::listSources()` method, which selects available table names from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` and so it doesn't "see" any available views.

### The solution

Change `DboMssql::listSources()` to select available table names from `sys.tables` or, if I'm wrong about `sys.tables`, to *additionally* select names from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS`.

So, not to mess with CakePHP core files, you'll have to create custom datasource, which extends DboMssql and overrides `::listSources()` method. To do so, you'll have to:

1. Create `<path/to/app>/models/datasources/dbo/dbo_custom_mssql.php`:

   ```
   <?php

   App::import('Datasource', 'DboMssql');

   class DboCustomMssql
           extends DboMssql
   {
       public
       function listSources()
       {
           $cache = DboSource::listSources();
           if ($cache != null) {
               return $cache;
           }
           $result = $this->fetchAll('SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM SYS.TABLES', false);
           if (!$result || empty($result)) {
               return array();
           } else {
               $tables = array();
               foreach ($result as $table) {
                   $tables[] = $table[0]['TABLE_NAME'];
               }
               DboSource::listSources($tables);
               return $tables;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Change `config/database.php` config: `'driver' => 'custom_mssql'`
3. Test

**NB:** The worst thing is that `DboMssql::listSources()` interface is kinda broken (w/o optional `$data` argument (like `Datasource::listSources()` declares)) and doesn't provide any point of extension, so, in order to have source list caching, we're forced to call `DboSource::listSources()` instead of broken `parent::listSources()`.

Answer (score 0):

I have SQL Server views being happily displayed. The main difference that I have to you is that I am using the mssql driver rather than the odbc_mssql driver. Perhaps you should try switching to that and figure out whatever problems you have there first.